# Using wpa_supplicant to select an access point

Tags: linux, debian, networking, wpa-supplicant

I have two access points in my home, and I connect to either one of them depending on which one I need. One runs behind a Tor router, the other is my normal access point.

Can I use `wpa_supplicant` to connect to either one? I do not want to enable roaming.

I usually connect to an access point like so:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

This was fine when I had one network, but how can I specify which AP to connect to now that I have 2 AP's in my interfaces file?

For now, I guess I could just create 2 config files but I'd really like to know how to achieve this using either wpa_supplicant or wpa_cli. For now I'll go through the man pages to see what I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 wireless access points too. Here's what I do:

Have `systemd` start `wpa_supplicant` at boot.

Put both access points in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. That looks something like:

```
network={
        ssid="Jan Vermeer of Delft"
        psk="SOmeThing"
        priority=3
}
network={
        ssid="Pieter Brueghel the Younger"
        psk="SomethngElse"
        priority=4
}
```

I use `wpa_cli` command line program to change from one access point to the other as I desire. The `list_networks` and `select_network` commands are about all you need there.

Comment: My config looks similar to yours. With wpa_supplicant running if I run `sudo wpa_cli` I get `could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (null) - retrying`. I think its something to do with it not being able to connect to the ctrl socket or something. Some guides suggest adding `ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant` to the config but that file does not exist for me. I'm on Debian Jessie if that's any help.

Comment: I have been following: http://www.fmepnet.org/debian_wpa.html

Comment: My bad, the file isn't mean to exist. Added that line and group 20 and it works. Many thanks :)